# Linkedin Javascript SDK - 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

Few hours ago, the Linkedin sign in API (used with [JS Sdk](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk)) seems to stop working. I'm aware about the changes in API permissions but I have not found notices regarding changes on the JS SDK. 
I have evereything configured to make the JS SDJ work with localhost, using: localhost:4500

When the html is loaded, the in.js is downloaded. Then a userspace.js also downloads and this tries to donwliad the following file: https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=0.0.2000-RC8.47643-1428&lang=en_US
which fails with a 503 error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:   78jxxkcl1yf0fu
        onLoad:
        authorize: true
        lang:      en_US
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

The JS download sequence triggered from the HTML is:

```
Request URL:http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request URL:https://www.linkedin.com/uas/js/userspace?v=0.0.1194-RC8.47400-    1428&apiKey=77xmy0q3cp6sie&onLoad=OnLinkedInFrameworkLoad&authorize=true&secure=1&lang=en_US
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Remote Address:23.197.237.95:443
Request URL:https://platform.linkedin.com/js/framework?v=0.0.2000-RC8.47643-1428&lang=en_US
Request Method:GET
Status Code:503 Service Unavailable
```

I tried using an invalid Api Key, and the error is reported correctly. The same if I use a different localhost address.
Is there any errors in my code? Or linkedin SDK is going to be deprecated?

Thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Well, The problem was yesterday only in some countries. For example, I'm in Argentina and I had this problem. But when I use HOLA (a proxy extension for GoogleChrome) and I do a request from USA or Spain, Linkedin works perfectly.
Today this problem in Argentina is fixed.